# Cannot change Button size and location, with eclipse RCP?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I'm using eclipse RCP to develop a user interface. I created some buttons and I want to change their size and location.I used the methods setLocation() and setSize() but didn't get any result:

```
Composite top = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
GridLayout layout1 = new GridLayout(2, true);
top.setLayout(layout1);
Button buttonEdit = new Button(top, SWT.PUSH);
buttonEdit.setText("Edit");
buttonEdit.setLocation(10,10);
buttonEdit.setSize(50, 20);
```

Any idea?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

When you use a layout for the parent `Composite` - in this case a `GridLayout` - the location and (sometimes) size is disregarded and calculated by the layout.

If you really want to use absolute layout - which cannot be recommended - then simply remove `top.setLayout(layout1)`.

If you find using a layout manager difficult, install the [SWT Designer](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/download.html).

Comment: Or use WindowBuilder, which is part of Eclipse 3.7.

Comment: Which the same software with a different name :-)